# How to change calico listening default port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, calico

I am a begginer on kubernetes and I can see on the latest calico.yaml file ([Install Calico on nodes](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/onpremises#install-calico-with-kubernetes-api-datastore-50-nodes-or-less)) the configuration for the listening default 9099 port.

I am deploying on a few nodes and that port (9099) is taken as other services are running in the background.

From the logs I can see:

```sh
2020-08-28 12:15:15.107 [ERROR][59] felix/health.go 246: Health endpoint failed, trying to restart it... error=listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9099: bind: address already in use
2020-08-28 12:15:16.108 [ERROR][59] felix/health.go 246: Health endpoint failed, trying to restart it... error=listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9099: bind: address already in use
2020-08-28 12:15:17.108 [ERROR][59] felix/health.go 246: Health endpoint failed, trying to restart it... error=listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9099: bind: address already in use
2020-08-28 12:15:18.109 [ERROR][59] felix/health.go 246: Health endpoint failed, trying to restart it... error=listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9099: bind: address already in use
```

The logs are coming from the pod:

```sh
kube-system              calico-node-d4ntt                               1/1     Running   0          9m41s
kube-system              calico-node-mjh4z                               0/1     Running   3          3m31s
kube-system              calico-node-p5lgf                               0/1     Running   2          3m34s
kube-system              calico-node-t4vmd                               0/1     Running   2          3m30s
```

How can we update this port? On the yml file I can not see the port.

I can see on the yml file the configuration:

```sh
listenPort:
                description: ListenPort is the port where BGP protocol should listen.
                  Defaults to 179
                maximum: 65535
                minimum: 1
```

But this is not the port that is blocking my deployment.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you have to add containerPort parameter to calico-node container part of `calico.yaml`:

First download `calico.yaml` file:

```sh
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -O
```

There is a DaemonSet in this yaml file, which has a container named `calico-node`, add `DaemonSet.spec.template.spec.containers.ports.containerPort parameter` to yaml file and change its value to something you want (any port you want). Something like this:

```yaml
containers:
        # Runs calico-node container on each Kubernetes node. This
        # container programs network policy and routes on each
        # host.
        - name: calico-node
          image: calico/node:v3.16.1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9090
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your hosts and firewalls allow the necessary traffic based on your configuration - [calico-kubernetes-requirements](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/requirements).

Set the `TYPHA_HEALTHHOST` or checked on what localhost is resolving to.
Similar solution: [felix-calico](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2146#issuecomment-416114114).

Also you can try to change livenessProve and readinessProbe:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
     path: /liveness
     port: 9099 #here you can change port
```

If above solutions will not work kill process on port 9099 and then reinstall Calico.

See more: [projectcalico-issue](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2146#issuecomment-542171417).

Also take a look: [calico-incubator](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws/issues/1381#issuecomment-403270288), [calico-felix](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws/issues/1440).

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you for providing so many links and information. I will give it a try and update the ticket.

Comment: Was my answer useful ?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to verify the solution. I upgraded my cluster to the latest (stable) version 1.19.0 and I had problems with deployment of Calico. I switched now to Weave Net. I do not want to downgrade my cluster so I can test the solution. I will launch later on another cluster I might try it at that point but unfortunately I can not currently verify it.

Comment: Did you manage to make some progress, test on another cluster ?